# Get position of an element inside scrollview

Tags: c#, xamarin, mobile, xamarin.forms

I am trying to achieve an event trigger when a certain element is in center of screen while scrolling from left to right or right to left, I tried scrollview but could not find any solution.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What errors did you get?

Comment: Could you tell us which toos you are using, which programming language etc.

Comment: I am using VS 2017, and C#, I have tried to use scrollview horizontally and tried to get position of button matching with screen width, so, I can detect if button is in center of screen or not,

Comment: @Matthew  But I think, scrollview does not give button position after scroll, it just shows same position of button which it show son screen load

Answer (score 0):

You need more of a description on stack overflow, but welcome.
I'm going to guess this is a .Net forms application.
Because I'm having trouble understanding if you are trying to create the event handler, or the actual "popup". Assuming it is a popup, you could do something like this when your event is triggered:

ToolstripDropDown could be useful for this.

an example is here:

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17502/Simple-Popup-Control

here is info on adding your elements:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-add-toolstrip-items-dynamically

and doumentation on how to center it is here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripdropdown.show(v=vs.110).aspx

```
//borrowed from link above
ToolStripDropDown popup = new ToolStripDropDown();
popup.Items.Add(youritems); //loop through them if you want, see link above
popup.Show(Point); /*pass in a point that is the middle of the screen or however you want to position it */
```

Comment: I think the OP is using Xamarin Forms not Win Forms